# How to reduce to an array without any pairs of elements close by a distant, while knowing the indices

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy

for example I have:

```
x = array([[0.       , 0.94],
           [0.9486833, 0.94],
           [1.8973666, 0.94],
           [2.8460498, 0.94],
           [0.9486833, 0.94]], dtype=float32)

y = array([   [1],
              [2],
              [3],
              [4],
              [5]], dtype=float32)
```

and since in x there are two elements that are close to each other by a distant, I only want to keep one so based on the elements in x that are close to each other by a threshold and I remove one, my result is:

```
x = array([[0.       , 0.94],

           [1.8973666, 0.94],
           [2.8460498, 0.94],
           [0.9486833, 0.94]], dtype=float32)

y = array([   [1],

              [3],
              [4],
              [5] ], dtype=float32)
```

So if I know which indices from x, I have kept or removed then I can also construct y that correctly correspond to the remaining elements of x.

In addition I have made the conversion from tensorflow to numpy array, if there was a suggestion within tensorflow, I would accept it.

Comment: Is the proximity rule transitive? What if a is close to b which is close to c but a and c aren't?

Comment: it's not transitive, so in the end I only don't want to see any pairs that are close by a threshold. For example, if there are three points on a line and the distance between consecutive points are very small, removing the middle point results in 2 points that are far enough, otherwise if the distance between the 2 new points was also too smal, one should be removed.